# MembershipUser.Email returns null even when email is stored in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership, membershipuser

my problem is, that I am not able to access the user's email, when using Membership.GetUser(username) method.
I need it when I am reset password. I receive the username in POST request.
My code looks like this:

```
...
System.Web.Security.MembershipUser user = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
    if (user != null)
     {   
         string emailAddress = user.Email;
...
```

I am sure that the user to whom I am trying to reset the password, has the email stored in database, but when I want to retrieve it user.Email is null.

Can somebody help me with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods you are using are for traditional ASP.NET membership, not SimpleMembership.  Here is the way to get that information from SimpleMembership.

```
var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
var email = user.Email;
```

You can [read more about accessing and customizing UserProfile here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).

There is also an [article on setting up password reset for SimpleMembership here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/04/password-reset-with-simplemembership.html) and the [source code is available here](http://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/).